# Is it possible to store image in database directely?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store image in database directly without storing it in a folder on my explorer. If possible than how? I am using `php` with `mysql` database to store image and i have define datatype `LONGBLOB` to store image in database. Below is my code:

```
   <?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_select_db($conn,'image') or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
$old = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$new = $_FILES['img']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($old,$new);

echo $sql = "INSERT INTO img(`img_name`) VALUES('$new')";
$exe = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($exe){
    echo "Image Uploaded Successfully....";

    }
}

echo $query = "Select `img_name` from `img`";
$ex = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <input type="file" name="img"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
            </div>
            <?php
                while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($ex)){

            ?>
            <div>
                <img height="50" width="50" src="<?php echo $res['img_name'];?>"/><br/>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you look up "PHP store image in database" on Google?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: It is, though it generally isn't recommended; store the file in the server filesystem, and just store a filepath in the database

Comment: It show me to store image in folder on my explorer and save the name only in a database, otherwise store the image on my explorer and store full image path on database.

Comment: @Mark yes as i mentioned it in comment i have refer that, but my requirement is mentioned as above in my question.

Comment: You are confusing three entirely different concepts: URL, disk path and, well, data.

Comment: I am not confusing, read my question properly i don't want to use move_uploaded_file() which store image in my folder on my explorer. I want to store it directly in database using LONGBLOB datatype  @Alvaro Gonzalez

Comment: You *are* confusing, read your *code* properly.

Comment: @BhattAkshay Why? You'd lose out on extensions and if done incorrectly you'll be fetching *megabytes* if not *gigabytes* from your database whenever you `SELECT`. Why would you want all the file data to be sent over the MySQL socket rather than PHP just reading from the filesystem? Let's also hope that you never have to do a backup/restore of the database if you save all your data in it.

Comment: I need it as per requirement in my project to stick it directly in database.

Comment: @BhattAkshay - then you really should be turning round and telling the person who specified this requirement that it's a really inefficient compared with using the filesystem - [take a look at the answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).... and shouldn't be used unless they have a very specific technical or business reason to use the database instead of the filesystem

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert the image into base64. something like this:

```
$path = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

It'd be better to save it as a string rather than BLOB if possible. If it has to be a BLOB you'd have to convert the string and then convert it back when you're retrieving from the database. If you store it as a string, the image will even work with the base64 as the src of the image.

Comment: I need my image in database directly don't want to store it in my folder in explorer. $path = 'myfolder/myimage.png'; I don't want this.

Comment: I've edited my response to work with your example. Apologies, i thought it obvious to just swap it out.

Comment: BLOB Columns can store binary data; while less efficeinet, this is a method to embed the binary image data directly in the markup

Comment: you could also embed base64 image data straight into the markup, rather than a BLOB, which is why i suggested using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],"latest.img");
            $instr = fopen("latest.img","rb");
            $image = addslashes(fread($instr,filesize("latest.img")));

            mysql_query ("insert into pix (mgdata) values ('".image."')");
```

And after delete uploaded image, image will be in DB

After you can send image from DB to browser

```
    $gotten = @mysql_query("select * from pix order by pid desc limit 1");
    if ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($gotten)) {
    $title = htmlspecialchars($row[title]);
    $bytes = $row[imgdata];
    } 

    // If this is the image request, send out the image

    if ($_REQUEST[gim] == 1) {
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    print $bytes;
    exit ();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend the `mysql_` functions. They've been deprecated for **years** and have been completely removed from PHP 7.